# I want several data series on one continuous Y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data set

```
means_long <- rbindlist(means, use.names = FALSE, fill = FALSE, idcol = "ID")
     ID divisions divs_20 mean20
  1:  1         1      20     19
  2:  1         2      20     19
  3:  1         3      20   19.3
  4:  1         4      20   20.2
  5:  1         5      20   19.2
  6:  1         6      20   18.5
  7:  1         7      20   19.1
  8:  1         8      20   17.8
  9:  1         9      20   19.6
 10:  1        10      20   19.9
 11:  1        11      20   20.7
 12:  1        12      20   21.4
 13:  1        13      20   21.4
 14:  1        14      20   20.6
 15:  1        15      20   22.2
 16:  1        16      20   23.1
 17:  1        17      20   22.5
 18:  1        18      20   23.3
 19:  1        19      20   24.4
 20:  1        20      20   24.4
 21:  2         1      15   14.9
 22:  2         2      15   14.8
 23:  2         3      15   14.2
 24:  2         4      15   12.9
 25:  2         5      15   12.2
 26:  2         6      15   12.9
 27:  2         7      15   13.3
 28:  2         8      15   13.6
 29:  2         9      15   12.7
 30:  2        10      15   12.9
 31:  2        11      15     12
 32:  2        12      15   12.7
 33:  2        13      15   12.9
 34:  2        14      15   14.7
 35:  2        15      15     15
 36:  2        16      15     15
 37:  2        17      15   16.7
 38:  2        18      15   17.1
 39:  2        19      15   18.9
 40:  2        20      15   18.6
 41:  3         1      10    8.5
 42:  3         2      10    8.4
 43:  3         3      10    9.3
 44:  3         4      10    8.4
 45:  3         5      10    7.8
 46:  3         6      10    7.9
 47:  3         7      10    7.8
 48:  3         8      10    7.8
 49:  3         9      10    7.5
 50:  3        10      10    6.7
 51:  3        11      10    6.1
 52:  3        12      10    6.2
 53:  3        13      10    6.4
 54:  3        14      10    5.8
 55:  3        15      10    5.5
 56:  3        16      10    5.1
 57:  3        17      10    5.4
 58:  3        18      10    5.5
 59:  3        19      10    5.8
 60:  3        20      10    6.3
 61:  4         1       5    4.9
 62:  4         2       5    5.3
 63:  4         3       5    5.5
 64:  4         4       5    5.2
 65:  4         5       5    5.2
```

I'm trying to create a graph that shows the mean after each division - I have 5 sets of data (each of 20 observations) and I want the graph to have 5 differently coloured lines to show comparison

I've been using:

```
ggplot(means_long, aes(x=divisions, y=mean20, colour=ID, group=ID)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Average number of kinetochore subunits after 20 cell divisions") + 
  xlab("Number of divisions") + 
  ylab("Mean number of kinetochore subunits") + 
  scale_colour_continuous(low = "#132B43", high = "#56B1F7", space="Lab", na.value="grey50", guide="legend")
```

This creates a graph where each set of data is plotted individually on the y-axis. All data points match up on the x-axis, but for EG, rather than the y-axis spanning 0 - 12, each data set spans 1-12 and so 1-12 is repeated 5 times up the y-axis.

I think it has something to do with the way the data frame is laid out but I can't work out how to change it.

Output for dput(means_long):

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), divisions = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L), divs_20 = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2), mean20 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 
8L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 27L, 26L, 
24L, 21L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 21L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 25L, 28L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 31L, 46L, 45L, 47L, 45L, 43L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 
42L, 41L, 37L, 38L, 40L, 36L, 35L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 39L, 48L, 
51L, 35L, 50L, 50L, 34L, 49L, 33L, 35L, 53L, 52L, 54L, 50L, 33L, 
53L, 36L, 36L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 63L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 61L, 
60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 60L, 59L, 58L, 57L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 55L
), .Label = c("17.8", "18.5", "19", "19.1", "19.2", "19.3", "19.6", 
"19.9", "20.2", "20.6", "20.7", "21.4", "22.2", "22.5", "23.1", 
"23.3", "24.4", "12", "12.2", "12.7", "12.9", "13.3", "13.6", 
"14.2", "14.7", "14.8", "14.9", "15", "16.7", "17.1", "18.6", 
"18.9", "5.1", "5.4", "5.5", "5.8", "6.1", "6.2", "6.3", "6.4", 
"6.7", "7.5", "7.8", "7.9", "8.4", "8.5", "9.3", "4.9", "5", 
"5.2", "5.3", "5.6", "5.7", "5.9", "0.1", "0.2", "0.3", "0.4", 
"0.7", "0.8", "1", "1.4", "1.6", "1.7", "1.9"), class = "factor")), 
.Names =  c("ID", "divisions", "divs_20", "mean20"), 
row.names = c(NA,  -100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),  .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000220788>)
```

Comment: please add the output of `dput(means_long)` to your question

Comment: Can you elaborate on what EG is? Are you looking for `facet_grid`?

Comment: i've now added that Thierry, thank you

Comment: @Axeman I just meant as an example, what I want to is one set of values on the y-axis, not 5

Comment: `mean20` is a factor. Use `means_long$mean20 <- as.numeric(as.character(means_long$mean20))`

Comment: It now tells me ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data class of numeric - does this mean i'll have to use a different package to plot it?

Comment: It works fine for me, just add that line before the `ggplot` call that you already had.

Comment: I've got it working - thank you so much @Axeman !!

Comment: @Jordan please add your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

My y-axis was a factor rather than a numerical value so using below code changed it to a numeric value.

```
means_long$mean20 <- as.numeric(as.character(means_long$mean20))
```

Now my graph has one scale y-axis for all 5 data sets